# SemanticZoom - How do I keep two ListView controls in selection synch?

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Using a `SemanticZoom` control in an MVVM project, I have two `ListView` controls with custom styles and panels, etc. so they display horizontally, there is no grouping or need for it.

I bind both to a `CollectionViewSource` in the view model.

When I click an item in the zoomed-out view, it doesn't take focus to that item in the zoomed-in view.

How can I achieve this?

Edit

Added XAML code:

```
    <SemanticZoom>
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
            <ListView
                Style="{StaticResource HorizontalListViewStyle}"
                SelectionMode="None"
                ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding BoardItems}" 
                ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ZoomedOutListViewItemContainerStyle}">
            </ListView>
        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
            <ListView x:Name="listView"
                Style="{StaticResource HorizontalListViewStyle}"
                SelectionMode="None"
                ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding BoardItems}"
                ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ZoomedOutListViewItemContainerStyle}">                    
            </ListView>
        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
    </SemanticZoom>
```

Comment: Is it two ListViews, one for zoomed out and one for zoomed in? If so, how are you setting the ZoomedOut items source? In the Code Behind? In either case, try making sure that both of your ZoomedInView and Out views have `ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="False"`. The ScrollChaining has been known to mess with it. Also, if your bound datasource changes, I've found that I need to re-set the ItemsSource of my ZoomedOutView, otherwise when it does a reference equality check, the two items will possibly come out different.

Comment: +1 for the ScrollViewer tip for other people's benefit, I already read about that. I tell you, I get paid well to write big XAML apps for a living, and it never gets any easier.

Comment: I'm going to write to Terry Adams who did a session at Build 2012 on all this, it should just work. I believe that if we don't complain loudly, then we can't expect things to improve, whether this be a bug, documentation problem, tooling, errors whatever, I've had it with spending months writing workarounds.

Comment: Definitely, or at least some kind of compiler warning, even just in Blend. There are so many little 'tips' or 'notes' that they hide away in the documentation that it can be daunting for even seasoned developers at times. I think 8.1 is going to fix some of these issues (partly due to the improved XAML support in VS2013). I wonder if some of these things could be put into something like ReSharper, as it seems like a Pattern that could be created. I'll message their team and look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In codebehind for the page (or using an attached property), handle the `ViewChangeStarted` event with this code:

```
    private void zoomyThingWoo_ViewChangeStarted(object sender, SemanticZoomViewChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SourceItem.Item != null)
        {
            e.DestinationItem.Item = e.SourceItem.Item;
        }
    }
```

That's it. The documentation makes it sound like `SemanticZoom` will just work with any two controls that implement ISemanticZoomInfo but it doesn't.

I raised a documentation bug with the XAML team in Redmond.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your `ZoomedInView` and `ZoomedOutView` need to have `ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="False"` in order to scroll properly.

Comment: Um, as per the comment in reply to your comment on the 16th, I've already set this.

Comment: I'm setting it as the answer so that people who come to see this question are able to easily find it (and know that the question has been answered). The FAQ requests that this be done.

Comment: I apologize if I wasn't clear Nate. I already had this setting in place and the problem is still there.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry. Let me see what I can find out.